# Como fazer para o texto sumir do campo WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Eu estou usando o wpf pela 1a vez, como é a declaração de um campo textbox em que eu tenha um texto (Ex: "Login") e quando eu clique nele ele suma e fique soh o ponteiro para eu começar a digitar?

Se não compreendeu como é esse texto um [exemplo do hotmail](http://hotmail.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já que você está começando, recomendo que tente implementar a funcionalidade como as outras respostas sugerem, só para entender melhor os mecanismos da plataforma.

Quando estiver seguro, confira a biblioteca [Extendend WPF Toolkit](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit), que possui diversos componentes WPF muito úteis. Um deles se chama [WatermarkTextBox](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/WatermarkTextBox) e fornece exatamente a funcionalidade que você precisa. Se precisar desse comportamente em mais que um lugar da sua aplicação, recomendo usar a biblioteca ao invés de implementar manualmente.

Exemplos de como utilizar o componente podem ser encontrados no segundo link.

Há, porém uma diferença quanto ao seu pedido original: neste componente, o texto original (no seu exemplo, "Login") some somente quando o usuário começa a digitar. Um comportamento similar pode ser observado em diversas caixas de texto do StackOverflow, como a caixa de 'Resumo da Edição' e de 'pesquisa'.

Answer (score 1):

Funciona perfeitamente:

```
<Grid>
<TextBox  Width="250"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="SearchTermTextBox" Margin="5"/>
<TextBlock IsHitTestVisible="False" Text="Insira o texto aqui" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" Foreground="DarkGray">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=SearchTermTextBox}" Value="">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Segue um exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao inserir um texto a marca d'água some...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: caraca, tem q fazer toda essa volta pra isso O.O?

Comment: Sim... é só copiar e colar que funciona. No TextBlock vc altera a propriedade Text com o texto que desejar.

Comment: Não entendi pq negativaram sendo que o exemplo faz exatamente o mesmo comportamento que o hotmail.com

Answer (score 0):

O recomendado é fazer como o amigo citou na outra resposta ...mas você pode tentar via código....tente assim:
crie um método para a marca d'água e chame esse método no seu construtor.

```
   private void marcaDagua(){
        txtLogin.Text = "Login";
        txtLogin.Foreground = Brushes.LightGray;
    }
```

chame ele no contrutor

```
 public SuaClasse() {
        InitializeComponent();
        marcaDagua();
    }
```

depois no evento GetFocus do seu TextBox escreva o codigo

```
   private void txtLogin_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        txtLogin.Text = string.Empty;
        txtLogin.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
    }
```